# Distinct ComboBox Items

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to convert sql to entity and I need to select distinct items. I thought this would work but its returning all the rows instead of the distinct items.

```
  Dim OrderNos = (From r In Orders.R3Delivery Where r.mainOrderNumber <> "" Select r).Distinct().ToList()
    For Each thisentry In OrderNos
        cbOrderNumbers.DisplayMember = thisentry.mainOrderNumber
        cbOrderNumbers.ValueMember = thisentry.mainOrderNumber

    Next
```

Also is their any good free sql to linq tools out their linquer good but its like 60 quid

Comment: I believe this has been answered on [this SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556077/distinct-in-linq-with-anonymous-types-in-vb-net)

Comment: `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` should not be the same field. You should not be setting these in a loop either - they are getting overwritten each iteration.

Comment: ``DisplayMember`` and ``ValueMember`` can be the same. I do agree that they shouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is comparing the entire object being returned, not just the order number.

If you only need the order numbers, changing this line should get you there:

```
Dim OrderNos = (From r 
                In Orders.R3Delivery 
                Where r.mainOrderNumber <> "" 
                Select r.mainOrderNumber).Distinct().ToList()
```

If you need the whole object, then it gets more complicated.