# Linq Group on Multiple Fields - VB.NET, Anonymous, Key

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am stumped.  I need help.  I have a DTO object with duplicates patient address data.  I need to get only the unique addresses.

```
Dim PatientAddressDto = New List(Of PatientAddress)

{Populate PatientAddressDto with lots of duplicate data}

PatientAddressDto = (From d In PatientAddressDto
                    Group d By PatientAddressDtoGrouped = New PatientAddress With {
                                                              .Address1 = d.Address1,
                                                              .Address2 = d.Address2,
                                                              .City = d.City,
                                                              .State = d.State,
                                                              .Zip = d.Zip
                                                              }
                  Into Group
                  Select New PatientAddress With {
                                                  .Address1 = PatientAddressDtoGrouped.Address1,
                                                  .Address2 = PatientAddressDtoGrouped.Address2,
                                                  .City = PatientAddressDtoGrouped.City,
                                                  .State = PatientAddressDtoGrouped.State,
                                                  .Zip = PatientAddressDtoGrouped.Zip
                                                  }).ToList()
```

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
PatientAddressDto = (From d In PatientAddressDto
                    Select New PatientAddress With {
                                                  .Address1 = d.Address1,
                                                  .Address2 = d.Address2,
                                                  .City = d.City,
                                                  .State = d.State,
                                                  .Zip = d.Zip
                                                    }).Distinct
```

and also

```
PatientAddressDto = PatientAddressDto.GroupBy(Function(p) New PatientAddress With {
                                                  .Address1 = p.Address1,
                                                  .Address2 = p.Address2,
                                                  .City = p.City,
                                                  .State = p.State,
                                                  .Zip = p.Zip
                                                    })
```

Comment: You were right on your comment, I will delete my answer since it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Have you tried selecting just the fields you want to check, then using .Distinct() on the result?

Comment: Mikey, yes I have.  I edited my comment above to include some alternatives.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) and make use of the [`Key` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531349.aspx) in order for equality to behave the way you expect (not required for C#).

Change your grouping by specifying the `Key` prefix and remove the `PatientAddress` usage :

```
Group d By PatientAddressDtoGrouped = New With {
    Key .Address1 = d.Address1,
    Key .Address2 = d.Address2,
    Key .City = d.City,
    Key .State = d.State,
    Key .Zip = d.Zip
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I am getting an error however stating that the  name or property being initialized must begin with '.'.

Comment: @wavedrop updated. You need to remove the `PatientAddress` in your `New` declaration while grouping so that you use an anonymous type.

Comment: It's not any anonymous type.  The type is "Patient Address"

Comment: @wavedrop right, but for the purpose of the grouping you can change the code as suggested above to use an anonymous type and get distinct results as expected. Your final `Select New PatientAddress` statement will ensure that the result in the end will be the class. Otherwise, you will need to modify your `PatientAddress` class and implement `IEqualityComparer`. That might be worth the effort if you intend to do lots of similar groupings and distinct calls, but with grouping we can use this shortcut.

Comment: interesting that the equivalent code in c# is more basic than a language that claims to be basic...

Answer (score 5):

I have found the following code to work which essentially accomplishes the grouping that I desire and populating the new object as type PatientAddress therefore eliminating the use of anonymous objects and the keyword Key.

Maybe someone can explain it, at the moment I can not.  Have a nice day.

```
Dim PatientAddressDto = New List(Of PatientAddress)

{Populate PatientAddressDto with lots of duplicate data}

PatientAddressDto = (From d In PatientAddressDto
                    Group d By d.Address1,
                                d.Address2,
                                d.City,
                                d.State,
                                d.Zip Into g =
                    Group Let grp = New PatientAddress With {.Address1 = Address1,
                                                                .Address2 = Address2,
                                                                .City = City,
                                                                .State = State,
                                                                .Zip = Zip}
                    Select grp).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

Its probably because `PatientAddress` does not override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.
An alternative is to us an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) for the grouping. Try writing:

```
Group d By PatientAddressDtoGrouped = New With { Key .Address1 = d.Address1, ....
```

Comment: do you have a recommendation?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try using an anonymous type instead of an existing class.

Comment: Thank you that worked and was very helpful.  I marked Ahmads as the answer because I could only pick one, it was slightly more helpful, and I think he had the final answer first (before your edit).  Thanks again.